# invalid command name "bind" - When Installing

Tags: installation, bind, embedded-system

I want to install [Red Suite 4](http://support.code-red-tech.com/CodeRedWiki/VersionInfo) (search on Google shows this problem is with installing  other apps too) on my 64bit machine.

I have installed the prerequisite packages: *linux32* and *ia32-libs* (for 32bit support).

When I try to install the app I get this error:

```
 sudo ./Installer_Red_Suite_4_4.2.3_255_Linux-x86 
    invalid command name "bind"
        while executing
    "::unknown bind Text <Tab>"
        ("uplevel" body line 1)
        invoked from within
    "uplevel 1 $next $args"
        (procedure "::obj::Unknown" line 3)
        invoked from within
    "bind Text <Tab>"
        (procedure "::InstallJammer::InitializeGui" line 19)
        invoked from within
    "::InstallJammer::InitializeGui "
        (procedure "::InstallJammer::InitInstall" line 68)
        invoked from within
    "::InstallJammer::InitInstall"
        (file "/installkitvfs/main.tcl" line 37049)
```

I've googled - InstallJammer is "Multiplatform GUI installer". What could be wrong - *bind* is bash command so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Can you run bind from the console?

Comment: yes, bind works alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with missing 32bit gtk2 library. Check out [this "bug" discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1048987?comments=all).

Answer (score 0):

My problem that caused exactly the same error message, was that I had mounted /tmp `noexec`.

The following will mount /tmp with execution rights:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```